# Chrome extension jquery selector

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Hi i try to create a chrome extension in which when i click the icon button a script will run and finds an element with specific ID. 
My manifest is like this :

```
{
"name": "Highlight some phrases",
"description": "Hightlight some pre defined text from websql database after page loads",
"version": "0.1",
"permissions": [
"tabs","<all_urls>"
],
"background": {
"scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"]
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"

},

"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
        ],

    "run_at": "document_start"         // pay attention to this line
    }
], 
"manifest_version":2
```

}

and the background.js is like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {

src = $('#UserName').val();
alert(src);

});
```

every time i click the icon the alert is always undefined. 
why is that happens?

Answer (score 0):

This happens probably because the DOM has not finished rendering yet. Try to put your script inside a window.onload or jQuery function like this:

```
$(function() {
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {

     var src = $('#UserName').val();
     alert(src);

  });
});
```

Also, be carefull not to declare variables without var, like you did with src, because you are polluting your global scope.

Comment: No still the same i get undefined. i also tried to change run_at also to all three options and still nothing.

Comment: Is there an input with id="UserName" in the page? What do you get with $('#UserName').length?

Comment: yes i have that id but when i changed the code to length no alert popups

Comment: i made a mistake on length and put () so now that i fixed that i get an alert but it is 0

Comment: That means there is no element with id="UserName" in the page the script is running, or that the element has not been rendered yet.

Comment: i have that id for sure. i also set ran_at document end so it can load all elements but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the documentation:

> In the case of "document_start", the files are injected after any
>   files from css, but before any other DOM is constructed or any other
>   script is run.

Your code works before the DOM load. It is normal that you get undefined.

Try changing
`document_start` to `document_end` in your manifest.

Comment: try removing this line  "run_at": "document_start", it is optional anyway.

Comment: i also removed it but still undefined

Answer (score 0):

one strange thing is that when i changed the code to `var src = $('body').html();
alert(src);`

the alert that i get is the two scripts that i load in the plugin

```
<script src='jquery.js></script>

 <script src='background.js></script>
```

why i get this as body html and not the whole html of my page?